# Equation alignment to left and equation number leveled to last line of the equation

Tags: equations

In my draft, the equation numbers are showing as Eq. 2.1  in text while they have to be as Eq. 1 and Eq. 2. Secondly, the equation number not leveled to the last line. Maybe some problem with my preamble. Here I post MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{nccmath, amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\title {\textbf{My title}}
\author[1]{Firstname Lastname}
\author[2]{Firstname Lastname}
\affil[1]{ABC University}
\affil[2]{XYZ University}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\begin{abstract}
Some text goes here.
\end{abstract}
\vfill
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Introduction}

\section{Methodology}
\subsection{Econometric estimation approach}

The econometric model is specified as Eq. \ref{eqt:1} below.
\begin{fleqn}[\parindent]
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{Imports}_{ijt} & = \exp \bigl(\alpha_{i} + \beta_{j} + \gamma_{t} + \delta_0 + \delta_1\ln \mathrm{Myvar}_{it} + \delta_1 \ln \mathrm{Myvar}_{jt}\; \\
&\phantom{{} = } +\delta_3 \ln \mathrm{Distance}_{ij} + \delta_4 \mathrm{Contiguity}_{ij} + \delta_5 \mathrm{Colony}_{ij} + \delta_6 \mathrm{EIA}_{ij}\bigr) + \epsilon_{ijt}
\end{aligned}
\label{eqt:1}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
Another econometric model is specified as Eq. \ref{eqt:2}. The definition of all variables are similar to as they are defined in Eq. \ref{eqt:1}.
\begin{fleqn}[\parindent]
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{Imports}_{ijt} & = \exp \bigl(\alpha_{i} + \beta_{j} + \gamma_{t} + \delta_0 + \delta_1 \ln \mathrm{Myvar}_{it} + \delta_1 \ln \mathrm{Myvar}_{jt} + \delta_3 \mathrm{Myvar}_{ijt}\; \\
&\phantom{{} = } +\delta_3 \ln \mathrm{Distance}_{ij} + \delta_4 \mathrm{Contiguity}_{ij} + \delta_5 \mathrm{Colony}_{ij} + \delta_6 \mathrm{EIA}_{ij}\bigr) + \epsilon_{ijt}
\end{aligned}
\label{eqt:2}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a my interpretation. Too long for a comment but I will use `flalign` option how in this example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
M_{ijt} & = \exp (\alpha_{it} +\beta_{jt} + \gamma_{ij}  +\delta_0+\delta_1\ln(\textnormal{Variable}_{ijt})) +\epsilon_{ijt} &
\label{eqt:1}
\end{flalign}

\begin{flalign}
M_{ijt}  & = \exp(\alpha_{it}+\beta_{jt}+\gamma_{ij} +\delta_0 + \delta_1 \ln(\textnormal{Variable}_{ijt}))\times \textnormal{High income}_i \notag\\
  &={}+\delta_2 \ln(\textnormal{Variable}_{ijt})\times \textnormal{Low income}_i) +\epsilon_{ijt} &
\label{eqt:2}
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You’ve probably misunderstood how `aligned` works. In this case, you should consider `align` (which is not the same as `aligned`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% Use fleqn option to set all equations aligned from the left (instead of centered)
%\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{align}
M_{ijt} &= \exp\bigl(\alpha_{it}+\beta_{jt}+\gamma_{ij}+\delta_0+\delta_1\ln\mathrm{Variable}_{ijt}\bigr)+\epsilon_{ijt},
\label{eqt:1}\\
\intertext{some more text (optional)}
M_{ijt} &= \exp\bigl(\alpha_{it}+\beta_{jt}+\gamma_{ij}+\delta_0+\delta_1\ln\mathrm{Variable}_{ijt}\times\mathrm{High\ income}_i \nonumber \\
&\phantom{{}=\exp\bigl(} +\delta_2\ln\mathrm{Variable}_{ijt}\times\mathrm{Low\ income}_i\bigr)+\epsilon_{ijt}.
\label{eqt:2}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: align example]

I removed all occurrences of `\;` (they were wrong). I also changed `exp` to `\exp` and `\textup{ln}` to `\ln`. I put `Variable`, `Highincome` and `Lowincome` into `\mathrm` for correct format.

Comment: I followed https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Spacing_in_math_mode so used the manual spacing. However, I would prefer not to use them anymore ... looks cleaner without.
And thanks for the help!

Comment: There are various options used in this post to typeset variable name in an equation e.g. `\mathrm`, `\text` and `\textnormal`. All three work well in terms of decent readability of the output. However, what could be the best option if to choose one... maybe `\mathrm'?

Comment: @AmosMachado In my opinion, it depends on the semantic meaning of your variables. What I propose, `\mathrm`, produces the same upright Roman letters just like `\sin`, `\cos`, `\exp`, `\ln`, etc (except `\sin` and so on are operator names, so there are some spacing differences). The other approaches, `\text` (from `amsmath`/`amstext`) and `\textnormal` will put `Variable`, `Highincome` in the style of surrounding text. So if you are typesetting inside a theorem, where text is all italic, your `Variable`, `Highincome` will also become italic. To me, the latter seems semantically wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`, which works  like the `subequations` environment, and can take as an optional argument the distance  from the text left margin at which  equations start. I took the opportunity to simplify your code (e.g. using `\ln` in the place of `\;\textup{ln}\;`). The placement of the equation number with the last line of an equation is made through the  optional argument `[b]` of the `aligned` environment (default is `c`). I also removed all the unnecessary manual spacings `(\;`), as I don't se why they should be needed.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[margin=1in, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\null\bigskip
\begin{fleqn}[\parindent]
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
M_{ijt} & = \exp \bigl(\alpha_{it} + \beta_{jt} + \gamma_{ij} + \delta_0 + \delta_1\ln \text{Variable}_{ijt}\bigr)+\epsilon_{ijt}
\end{aligned}
\label{eqt:1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
M_{ijt} & = \exp \bigl(\alpha_{it} + \beta_{jt} + \gamma_{ij} + \delta_0 + \delta_1\ln \text{Variable}_{ijt}\times \text{Highincome}_i\; \\
&\phantom{{} = } + \delta_2\ln \text{Variable}_{ijt}\times \text{Lowincome}_i\bigr) + \epsilon_{ijt}
\end{aligned}
\label{eqt:2}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility for the second equation (better looking, in my opinion) with `alignedat`:

```
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}[b]{2}
M_{ijt} & = \exp \bigl(\alpha_{it} + \beta_{jt} + \gamma_{ij} + \delta_0 & & + \delta_1\ln \text{Variable}_{ijt}\times \text{Highincome}_i\; \\
& & & + \delta_2\ln \text{Variable}_{ijt}\times \text{Lowincome}_i\bigr) + \epsilon_{ijt}
\end{alignedat}
\label{eqt:2}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
```

[image]

Comment: I prefer `\phantom{{}=\exp\bigl(}` because of context :)

Comment: @RuixiZhang: Why that?

Comment: The `+\delta_2\ln...` is part of the sum, which is inside `\exp\bigl(...\bigr)` right? So I prefer `+\delta_2\ln...` to start at the right edge of `\bigl(` to visualize which group it belongs to.

Comment: I see. Note I proposed another alignment, with the two `δ_i ln` aligned.

Comment: Yep, that works too :) Either way, typography enhances the writing.